# How to use codebird.js to search twitter API for matching users?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm really stuck trying to get this twitter library (https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js) to return search results rather than a user timeline.

I can't find out where to pass the search parameters to it.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
       var cb = new Codebird();
        cb.setConsumerKey("<fill in>","<fill in>");
        cb.setToken('<fill in>','<fill in>');  

        cb.__call('users/search', {
            'user' : '<fill in>',  // ??
            }
        );

        function tweets_callback (result)
        {
            // do something with the result 
        }
```

But it keeps throwing an error, does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not documented at all! This is how you do it:

```
   var cb = new Codebird();
    cb.setConsumerKey("<fill in>","<fill in>");
    cb.setToken('<fill in>','<fill in>');  

    cb.__call('users/search', {
        'q' : '<fill in>',
        'callback' : 'search_callback',
        }
    );

    function search_callback (result)
    {
        // do something with the result 
    }
```

Comment: the format of the url looks suspicious to me; should it not be `"users_search"`?

Comment: Note that the syntax for the `__call()` method in Codebird has changed since this answer was posted. See the [Codebird documentation here](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js#2-usage-examples).

Answer (score 1):

Line 5 should be:

```
cb.__call('users_search', {
```

This is documented here: https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-js#3-mapping-api-methods-to-codebird-function-calls